# aws_ec2_client_vpn_route for sunbnets in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to create vpn client routes between 3 vpc subnets and 7 CIDRs. Each CIDR should create route to each subnet. How to do it?

```
`variable "cidr_blocks" {
  description = ""
  default     = {
    "192.10.0.0/16" = 1
    "192.15.0.0/16" = 2
    "192.19.0.0/16" = 3
    "192.16.0.0/16" = 4
    "192.29.0.0/16" = 5
    "192.14.0.0/16" = 6
    "192.71.0.0/16" = 7
  }
}

 data "aws_subnet_ids" "test_subnet_ids" {
  vpc_id = "vpc-0ad0aa09b316f37a7"
 }
 data "aws_subnet" "test_subnet" {
   count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)}"
   id    = "${tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)[count.index]}"
 }

 output "subnet_cidr_blocks" {
   value = ["${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"]
 }
 resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_route" "example" {
   for_each = var.cidr_blocks

   client_vpn_endpoint_id = aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint.test-vpn.id
   destination_cidr_block = each.key
   target_vpc_subnet_id   = "${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"
 }`
```

Expected to see routes.
 `Error: Incorrect attribute value type │  │   on main.tf line 172, in resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_route" "example": │  172:   target_vpc_subnet_id   = "${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}" │     ├──────────────── │     │ data.aws_subnet.test_subnet is tuple with 3 elements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `test_subnet` by indices. Your `cidr_blocks` values can be used for it.

```
 resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_route" "example" {
   for_each = var.cidr_blocks

   client_vpn_endpoint_id = aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint.test-vpn.id
   destination_cidr_block = each.key
   target_vpc_subnet_id   = data.aws_subnet.test_subnet[each.value].id
 }
```

But according to error message you have only 3 subnets and you want to use 7 cidr in this case. You will get another error.

```
 resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_route" "example" {
   for_each = var.cidr_blocks

   client_vpn_endpoint_id = aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint.test-vpn.id
   destination_cidr_block = each.key
   target_vpc_subnet_id   = data.aws_subnet.test_subnet[each.value % len(data.aws_subnet.test_subnet)].id
 }
```